# CLI can't recognize the "more" commands

Tags: command-line-interface

trying to create my stack in CloudFormation using cli command, but it popped with error when i run this command" aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name berarp --template-body file://app-infra.yml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --region us-east-1
the error i get is:
***'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file*.**

expected to run that cli command to create the stack, i have tired to make changes in PATH but didn't work

Comment: I don't see "more" anywhere in that command.

Comment: Could you show us your `app-infra.yml` file?